# How to change the size of a UICollectionView as a factor of screen size?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout

There is a `UICollectionView` embedded inside a `UIViewController`. The requirement is to have the `UICollectionView`'s height always equal to half the screen size. What has been tried so far is:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  self.caCollectionView.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width
  self.caCollectionView.frame.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height / 2
}
```

This doesn't seem to be taking effect when built and run.
Is there something missing? 
Please help. Thank you in advance.

Screenshot added: Pink area is the `UIViewController` and white area is the `UICollectionView`

[image]

Comment: Show the current output/screenshot.

Comment: @Imad please see the updated output/screenshot. Thank you for replying.

Comment: Do you use constraints?

Comment: @anhtu not using any storyboard constraints. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you also move bottom view up?

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  self.caCollectionView.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width
  self.caCollectionView.frame.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height / 2
  self.pickAnotherView.frame.origin.y = self.caCollectionView.frame.origin.y+self.caCollectionView.frame.size.height
  self.pickAnotherView.frame.height = self.view.frame.height-self.caCollectionView.frame.size.height
}
```

You can do this on storyboard with constraint.

1. set equal height[image]
2. set multiplier to 0.5(half of view height)[image]

Comment: Very happy to help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Update Frame always in viewDidLayoutSubviews and use bounds instead of frame.

like

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
  {

        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        self.caCollectionView.frame.size.width = self.view.bounds.size.width 
        self.caCollectionView.frame.size.height = self.view.bounds.size.height / 2
  }
```

Comment: [@Jaydeep Vyas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6028575/jaydeep-vyas) Thank you for the response. I tried updating as per your code but still getting the same output. Please refer to the output screenshot that I'm getting. It has been updated in the original post.

Comment: @asdiu i think you have less number of images have try with more images, and for less number of images you have to increase collectionview cell size..

Comment: will definitely try it out. Thank you again.